# Multiple lights question

Tags: lighting, switch

I have a switch that turns multiple lights on. But I make some recent renovations and while maintaining the current switch I want to control each light individually too with different phases / hot lines independent from each other and from phase #1.

I try to make a schema.

[image]

Is this possible? How two phases can control the same light?

Thank you.

Comment: What do phases have to do with switching lights?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: "Phase" is a word that has special meaning in electrical.  Given that you called out 4 of them, you surely do not mean the electrical term.

Comment: Portugal, Europe.
I mean phase because all of them wil be powered with different lines not the same. But it make no difference could be the same as they work as my initial question:
Switch #1 turn on or off all lights at the same time.
Other switchs only control one light and there is no connection beteween switch #1 and the others.
For example if switch / lamp #2 is turned and you turn on switch #1 all lamps will be on. When you turn switch #1 off all lamps, except lamp #2, will be off. And you turn switch #2 off all of them are off.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix supplies like that for numerous reasons.  Top of the list is the rule that **currents must be equal in every cable or conduit** i.e. cancel each other out/sum to zero.  What goes out on hot comes back on neutral. All of it, no crisscrossing to other cables.    If a cable has are two hots, then counting source current as positive and return as negative, hot1+hot2+neutral=0.

You should also get clear on the switch logic you actually want.  Often people have trouble describing (specifically enough to write software code for it) what exactly they want. What they want is a butler.  Or if they know exactly, as you do here, they find after living with it that isn't what they wanted after all.

So **the simplest way to do this problem is smart switches** such as Insteon or Homekit, which install in a code compliant fashion, and you can program to exactly the behaviors you want.  **That is what I recommend**.

---

But if you want to hardwire it, Commander Adama...

one option to wire this is to have supply hot/neutral (black/white) come into junction box #1 with a switch.  The switch's 2 terminals get black and red pigtails. (Red=master switched-hot).

From there you have three cables which are /3 (black red white).  As it works out, things are color coded: white for neutral, black for always-hot, red for master-switched-hot.  The three cables tie into the same colors in junction box 1, and then split, never to rejoin.  Red will be hot in the entire network anytime switch #1 is on.

The first /3 cable goes onto junction box #2. Between that junction box and light #1, 2-wire+ground /2 cable is used, except its black conductor is re-marked with blue tape for individual-lamp switched-hot.   There is also a 3-way switch there.  The two brass screws get black and red from the /3 cable (always-hot and master-switched-hot).  The black common screw gets the blue wire (lamp swithed).   The two neutrals get joined with a wirenut.

The same thing happens in junction box #3 to lamp 2... And junction box #4 to lamp 3.   Except as described here, boxes 2-4 and lamps 1-3 do not connect to each other in any way whatsoever.

Currents are equal (canceling) in every cable.

The 3-way switches in boxes 2-4 have 2 positions.  In one position, they connect master-switched-hot to their lamp, yielding to switch #1‘s setting. In the other position, they connect always-hot to their lamp, overriding switch #1.

Comment: Thanks Harper.
Is there any change that you make a shcema out of your explanation? I'm not a electric expert so I was lost at your explanation, sorry.

Comment: No chance, I do not have access to my usual drawing software.

Comment: If I understand right... Something like this?

http://i67.tinypic.com/so766v.jpg

Comment: Exactly.  Except for wire colors, I keep the black black, and make the blue from the 3-way (UK 2-way) to the lamp.

Comment: you mean like this?
http://i65.tinypic.com/68vn04.jpg

Comment: Yup, that's it exactly.

Comment: And if I want to put on a PIR sensor instead of switch #2? I think there is no 3 way PIR sensor or does it?

Comment: Well, you've got always-hot there, fit the PIR and have it drive a second redundant lamp.   Or you could use a relay.  Keep in mind you cannot sever power to a PIR, or it loses its memory and takes a day or two to get calibrated again.

Comment: Even the PIR sensors that have manual control switchs? For instance this one https://mauser.pt/catalog/mproductimage.php?id=eKfOtSB2CU5T6i%2Brq%2BDkHOpfpGN1SZXkUIyNQwWtxEQ%3D (seen in https://mauser.pt/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=77394)?

Comment: I can't read portugese but I don't see where that one shows a manual control. The thing between PIR and N is the lamp.

Comment: Manual control on the green signed part - http://i67.tinypic.com/70v2aq.jpg

Comment: @pestevao oh, those are DIP switches, **those are for one-time configuration**.  They wear out quickly with daily use.  I've worn them out.  I would be surprised if one of them was a manual override, but if it was... What you could do, what I have done, is go behind the board and solder fine wires onto the DIP terminals you want to throw daily, and bring that out to a real switch.  That wiring would need to use mains wiring methods and be treated as if it were 120/230V.

Answer (score 0):

In your schematic diagram, all lamps will light when any one switch is closed.

Don't think in terms of "phases", that will get you in trouble. Think in terms of "circuits" and you really only want one circuit and 4 switches. If the intent is to just have switch #1 as a "master" switch that controls everything else, then you simply branch off of that circuit to feed the other 3 switches. In other words Switch #1 is in SERIES with Swites 2-4, Switches 2-4 are in parallel with each other. So if switch #1 is on, any of the others can control their respective lamps, then if switch #1 is off, everything is off and Switches 2-4 have no effect.

If the intent is to have Switch #1 be capable of ***overriding*** the state of any of the other 3 switches, where any switch 2 through 4 can turn it's light on or off, and so can switch #1, I can't think of how that can be done.

Comment: No. Switch #1 turn on or off all lights and the others only controls on light at a time. Even if switch / lamp #2 is turned on, turning on switch #1 will make all lights to turn on. Switching it off, only the lights that switch is on will remain on.

Comment: @pestevao, your diagram doesn't do that.  It has four parallel switches energizing all of the lights on a shared wire.  If any one or more switch is on, all lights will be on.

Comment: Yeap. Harper help me on the schematics on other comment thread. It end like this: http://i65.tinypic.com/68vn04.jpg